# How do I model subpanels correctly using Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, subclass

I have a panel (see BasePanel below) that has a list of items and an "action"-bar where buttons are placed. Clicking these buttons makes changes to the items in the list via models.

Now I want the same panel but with slightly different buttons (see CustomPanelA and CustomPanelB below). I have about three configurations for the buttons in the panel.

**How can I model this? I thought to use `wicket:child` but since the buttons are inside another wicket component that did not work.**

*BasePanel.java*

```
class BasePanel extends Panel {
    public BasePanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        // note: I need this container for refreshing using AJAX
        WebMarkupContainer outer = new WebMarkupContainer("outerContainer");
        outer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(outer);

        // ... create listview
        outer.add(new ListView("items") { /* implementation of listview */ };

        // This container is necessary to show/hide the buttons
        WebMarkupContainer actionbar =  new WebMarkupContainer("outerContainer");
        actionbar.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        // ... create default buttons
        actionbar.add(new Link("add") { /* implementation of link */ );
    }
}
```

*BasePanel.html*

```
<html>
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="outerContainer">
         <div wicket:id="actionbar" >
               <a wicket:id="add">Add</a>
         </div>
         <div wicket:id="items">
               <!-- ... markup for items is here -->
         </div>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

*CustomPanelA.java*

```
class CustomPanelA extends BasePanel {
    public CustomPanelA (String id) {
        super(id);

        // add additional buttons only
        actionbar.add(new Link("actionA1") { /* implementation of link */ );
        actionbar.add(new Link("actionA2") { /* implementation of link */ );
    }
}
```

*CustomPanelA.html*

```
<html>
<wicket:extend>
     <a wicket:id="actionA1">ActionA1</a>
     <a wicket:id="actionA2">ActionA2</a>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

*CustomPanelB.java*

```
class CustomPanelB extends BasePanel {
    public CustomPanelB (String id) {
        super(id);

        // add additional buttons only
        actionbar.add(new Link("action_b1") { /* implementation of link */ );
        actionbar.add(new Link("action_b2") { /* implementation of link */ );
    }
}
```

*CustomPanelB.html*

```
<html>
<wicket:extend>
     <a wicket:id="action_b1">Action b1</a>
     <a wicket:id="action_b2">Action b2</a>
</wicket:extend>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions of your issue. I will show you one of them.

As you mentioned `<wicket:child/>`-based approach, then I will build my decision on it. Your `BasePanel` will be abstract class, which will hold all your components that already in it, except action links. It will provide one abstract method, called, for example `addActionLinks`:

```
class abstract BasePanel extends Panel {
    public BasePanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        //...your code.
        WebMarkupContainer actionBar = ...;

        //call this abstract method to add links in actionBar.
        addActionLinks( actionBar );
    }

    public abstract void addActionLinks( WebMarkupContainer container );
}
```

HTML:

```html
<wicket:panel>
    ...
     <div wicket:id="actionbar" >
        <wicket:child/>
     </div>
    ...
</wicket:panel>
```

And for other panels you just implement `addActionLinks` method:

```
class CustomPanelA extends BasePanel {
    public CustomPanelA (String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    protected void addChildren ( WebMarkupContainer container )
    {
        actionbar.add(new Link("actionA1") { /* implementation of link */ );
        actionbar.add(new Link("actionA2") { /* implementation of link */ );
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```html
<wicket:extend>
    <a wicket:id="actionA1">ActionA1</a>
    <a wicket:id="actionA2">ActionA2</a>
</wicket:extend>
```

Of course you need to implement another panel with your `BasePanel` action link, removed from my implementation (create `DefaultBasePanel` class for example).

Also, you can create another `ListView` for action links in your `BasePanel` and also fetch them from one method, overriden by subclasses.

Also, maybe, using fragments could solve your issue too. You can look [here](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/usingfragments.html) to learn more about fragments.

I think, that there are more approaches, but for some reason this one came to my mind. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow thats a lot of information. Thanks for showing different ways how to do this.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think a much better solution is to use RepeatingViews. This way you don't even need to have html for the subpanels.

*BasePanel.java*

```
class BasePanel extends Panel {

protected final RepeatingView actionbar;

public BasePanel(String id) {
    super(id);

    // note: I need this container for refreshing using AJAX
    WebMarkupContainer outer = new WebMarkupContainer("outerContainer");
    outer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(outer);

    // ... create listview
    outer.add(new ListView("items") { /* implementation of listview */ };

    // This container is necessary to show/hide the buttons
    actionbar =  new RepeatingView("action");

    // ... create default buttons
    actionbar.add(new Link("add") { /* implementation of link */ }.
       setBody(Model.of("Add"));
}
}
```

*BasePanel.html*

```
<html>
<wicket:panel>
<div wicket:id="outerContainer">
     <div class="actions">
           <a wicket:id="action"></a>
     </div>
     <div wicket:id="items">
           <!-- ... markup for items is here -->
     </div>
</div>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

*CustomPanelA.java*

```
class CustomPanelA extends BasePanel {
public CustomPanelA (String id) {
    super(id);

    // add additional buttons only
    actionbar.add(new Link("actionA1") { /* implementation of link */ );
    actionbar.add(new Link("actionA2") { /* implementation of link */ );
}
}
```

*CustomPanelB.java*

```
class CustomPanelB extends BasePanel {
public CustomPanelB (String id) {
    super(id);

    // add additional buttons only
    actionbar.add(new Link("action_b1") { /* implementation of link */ );
    actionbar.add(new Link("action_b2") { /* implementation of link */ );
}
}
```

Note: inside the RepeatingView you can add any component that inherits the markup of the RepeatingView component. Just make sure you don't add the same component id twice and you'll be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I have mentioned `ListView` approach ( and consider it is similar to `RepeatingView` ), but in some cases you need to have markup for better element placing (for example wrap links into table) and styling (to allow put css tags via html, not to use `AttributeAppender` or overriding ). In this case you have to put all markup from parent panel into subpanel. Also, your approach have to use method where you place links, because otherwise all subpanels will have link "add" from `BasePanel`.

Comment: Sure, the "add" button is optional, creating an overridable method also makes total sense. 

I find it best not to have markup for such components, using AttributeAppenders and setBody() a much better route.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer. Though this is a perfectly valid solution I preferred Michaels answer because I can have different markup for the subpanels. ;-)